# How to attain overloading without copying the complete method if only a minor change is needed?

Tags: c#, java, coding-style

Consider these methods (`int` used as parameter input to simplify the Example. But it can be any datatypes and must not be same)

```
        public int Multiply(int a, int b)
        {
            int c=1;
            return (a * b * c);
        }
        public int Multiply(int a, int b, int c)
        {
            return (a * b * c);
        }
```

Suppose these methods were written long, Then how could I avoid copying the complete method?

Comment: You mean like having one call the other?

Comment: I want to make the third parameter optional. For this I don't want to make  a complete copy of the above method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one call cal be reduced to another more general call with appropriate parameters, then this is the preferred option. (See Inisheer and Jeremy Thompson's suggestions).

In the general case, however, when this can't be done, I suggest breaking the large operation into smaller meaningful ones. This way, one can implement different variants of the operation in subclasses, without repeating too much code.

Comment: This answer is not complete without mentioning @Inisheer, Jeremy Thompson and others as well. Selected this as best answer because its the conclusion

Answer (score 4):

Overloaded methods can call each other so you can **avoid copying the complete method** by extending the functionality, eg:

```
public int Multiply(int a, int b)
{
        return Multiply(a,b,1);
}
public int Multiply(int a, int b, int c)
{
        return (a * b * c);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In C# you can use optional arguments with default values:

```
public int Multiply(int a, int b, int c = 1)
{
     return (a * b * c);
}
```

And can be used like:

```
int a = Multiply(2, 3);    // 2 * 3 * 1 = 6
int b = Multiply(2, 3, 4); // 2 * 3 * 4 = 24
```

Comment: This is the thing somewhat I needed. But what if I don't want the Parameter int c not at all. I can avoid by checking condition for (if c!=1) , But still any other way?

Comment: To add, if .NET would ever allow math with generic types, life would be easy.

Answer (score 2):

Something like :

```
private static int Multiply(params int[] nums)
{
    int result = 1;
    foreach (int num in nums)
    {
        result *= num;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The above method can be written using Linq

```
private static int Multiply(params int[] nums)
{
    return nums.Aggregate(1, (current, num) => current*num);
}
```

Example :

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        int ans1 = Multiply(1, 2, 3, 4);         // 24
        int ans2 = Multiply(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);      // 120
        int ans3 = Multiply(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);   // 720

    }
```

Comment: i have assumed you have similar ones, in case of different ones, you have to proceed with normal way the overloads are created

Comment: one other way would be to pass `params objectt[]` but that may get complicated depending on your need!

Comment: @SubinJacob At some point you're just going to have to bite the bullet and write the code. One method to do everything isn't really feasible nor easy to upkeep.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can override it using method with varg argument.
Since already available methods cover 2 and 3 argument , any number of inputs can represented by using 1,2,3.

Heres a sample code that whipped up , which reuses the overloaded method.

**Code**

```
/**
 * @author Sudhakar Duraiswamy
 *
 */
public class Reuse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reuse r = new Reuse();
        int[] rr = {1,2,3};

        System.out.println(r.Multiply(rr));

        int[] rr1 = {1,2,3,3};
        System.out.println(r.Multiply(rr1));

        int[] rr2 = {1,2,3,3,2};
        System.out.println(r.Multiply(rr2));
    }

    public int  Multiply(int... arg){
        int result = 1;
        if(null != arg && arg.length >0){

            if(arg.length ==1){
                result =  arg[0];
            }else if(arg.length ==2){

                result =  Multiply(arg[0],arg[1]);
            }else if(arg.length >=3){               
                int remainingSize  = arg.length % 3;

                for(int i=0;i< arg.length-remainingSize ;i= i+3){                   
                    result = result * Multiply(arg[i], arg[i+1], arg[i+2]);                 
                }

                if(remainingSize == 2){             
                    result =result * Multiply(arg[arg.length-2], arg[arg.length-1]);
                }else if(remainingSize == 1){
                    result = result * arg[arg.length-1];
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public int Multiply(int a, int b)
    {
        int c=1;
        return (a * b * c);
    }
    public int Multiply(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return (a * b * c);
    }
}
```